# Sending JSON Object from Javascript to Silverlight then triggering an event to update Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, json

I am building a web application that basically consists of a set of HTML forms that, when the user updates them, updates a client-side Javascript Object Literal. That Object Literal is then converted to a JSON string and passed to the server for processing upon form submission.

**User fill out form -> local javascript updates client-side JS Object Literal -> user presses submit -> JS Object Literal Converted to JSON object -> JSON Posted to Server -> server processes JSON object**

Part of this application includes a visualization of the contents of the form. The visualization is very simple, consisting of a set of concentric circles. I am currently using HTML5 Canvas to create that visualization but would like to change the viz to utilize Silverlight as I would get better cross-browser results with hopefully less code.

My question is if it is possible to send a JSON string to a Silverlight application that is embedded in my client-side form and then trigger an event that updates the viz once that JSON object is received...all without a page reload.

Is this even possible with Silverlight and javascript? If so, a tutorial that covers this would be very helpful.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2010 if that makes a difference.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that - the [HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28VS.95%29.aspx) is a feature in Silverlight which allows JS code to call SL functions and vice-versa. Take a look at the link above for more information.

Comment: +1.  @Leon:  Reading through those pages on MSDN should give you a good idea how this is done.  You might want to consider whether you really do want to pass a JSON string into Silverlight or the simply pass what you are calling the "JS Object Literal" into Silverlight.  For a complex nested structure JSON may be better when used with the DataControlJsonSerializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for guiding me down the right path. These links also helped: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414(v=VS.95).aspx AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx